# How to call different different menus at same page in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I am using WordPress 3.0.4. I have created approximate 10 page through admin from

```
Dashboard->Pages->Add New->Update
```

After that I have created two menu from Dashboard->Appearance->Menu->

The first menu name is `header-top-navigation`. Second menu name is `header-bottom-navigation`

After that check the page and `add to menu` which I need in top header (header-top-navigation) and other pages added to (header-bottom-navigation).

How to call these different menu on frontend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [wp_nav_menu()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) in your theme files.
To insert the menu header-top-navigation

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'header-top-navigation' )); ?>
```

Comment: Ya I am using the same but only I am using this twice one for `header-top-navigation` and other for `header-bottom-navaigation`

Comment: Both I am using in `header.php` only one is working at a time mean when I comment one then second start working and when I comment second then first start working